# Solving an example using Bayes formula

Tags: probability

In the production of certain electronic devices , a fraction of 2% of the production is defective . A quick test detects a defective device with probability 95%. However, with prob 10%, it gives a false alarm for an intact device .
1)If the test gives an alarm,what is the prob that the device just tested is indeed defective .Use Bayes formula .

**Can someone help me?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An "intant device"?  Perhaps you meant "intact".  "Non-defective" would be better because a device can be "intact" and still not work!

I am not going to use "Bayes"  because I really don't like it!  Instead, here is how I would solve this problem"
  Imagine 10000 such devices.  2% of them, 200, are defective, 9800 are not.  The test detect 98% of the 200 defective devices or 196.  It also labels 10%, 980 of the non-defect00ive devices as "defective".  So you have a total of 980+ 196= 1176 devices labeled "defective" when only 196 are!  The probability that a defice labeled "defective" really is defective is 196/1176= 49/299, approximately 16%.

Perhaps you can use that as a check on your "Bayes" solution.